# Unable to retrieve data from local storage in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am getting an empty array when trying to retrieve localStorage as part of my playwright e2e test. When running the `Object.entries(localStorage)` command in page console, I can successfully retrieve the object with key, value pairs from local storage but when using `page.evaluate` method from playwright I am getting an empty array

Below is the playwright code

```
test(`[Given] a user logs into app with all roles [Then] user should be assigned with right permissions`, 
async({page}) => {
        await expect(websiteWidget).toBeVisible();

    await test.step(`Log into platform as a user with all roles`, async() => {
        await platform.login(process.env.allRoles, process.env.password);
    });

    await test.step('Check correct permissions are assigned ', async() => {
        const permissions = await page.evaluate(async () =>  Object.entries(localStorage))
        console.log(permissions);
});
```

});

[image]

User can log into application correctly. Can someone help me understand why am I getting an empty array with above code and if there is way to get the local storage from web page so that I can fetch key, value pairs that I need for my testing/assertions?

Above is the output o of `Object.entries(localStorage)` command in page console

Comment: A runnable [mcve] would be useful to see. You don't need to call `JSON.stringify()`, Playwright does that for you.

Comment: @ggorlen - I added the complete code of my test in the main question. I can login successfully but get empty local storage object. Not sure if playwright tries to access localStorage before page is completed loaded and localStorage object is available.

Comment: What's the site? `platform` is undefined so the example isn't complete. If you can't share the site, try to reproduce it on a sample page. `page.evaluate()`'s' callback doesn't need to be `async`.

Comment: @ggorlen I executed the same code against google site and another public site and my code works fine and retrives localStorage. For some reason, on my site it is not able to retrieve the it. I have to log into my application and then retrive data from localStorage that I need. to answer your original question, the command `await platform.login(process.env.allRoles, process.env.password);` is logging into the application

Comment: I can't say either without seeing the site. Is it possible local storage is set after your `evaluate` call? Is the site blocking you if it's headless? Running code in the console != Playwright, so that's no guarantee the script works. I can tell what `await platform.login(process.env.allRoles, process.env.password);` does but I can't run it.

Comment: Here is the updated code that would successfully retrieve  storage
`await test.step('Check correct permissions are present in local storage ', async() => {
            await expect(locator).toBeVisible();
            const permissions = await page.evaluate(() =>  Object.entries(localStorage))
            console.log(permissions);
    });`

Comment: Please [edit] code into the post. Or are you saying this works?

Comment: @ggorlen By adding an assertion before calling the `evaluate` method the code works. I have updated code in the post to reflect the code that works now

Comment: Excellent, thanks for confirming and self answering. That said, it's still pretty unuseful for future visitors since they won't be able to run the code and see the problem, so it's sort of a specific quirk to whatever your actual use case happens to be. So if you can make it self-contained and reproducible, that's a more useful resource for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add an assertion before evaluate method for page to wait longer so that localStorage is populated

test(`[Given] a user logs into app with all roles [Then] user should be assigned with right permissions`,
async({page}) => {
await expect(websiteWidget).toBeVisible();

```
await test.step(`Log into platform as a user with all roles`, async() => {
    await platform.login(process.env.allRoles, process.env.password);
});

await test.step('Check correct permissions are assigned ', async() => {
    await expect(locator).toBeVisible();

    const permissions = await page.evaluate(async () =>  Object.entries(localStorage))
    console.log(permissions);
```

});